# Trim left of a character in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying find a sub string from my data.

The format of the data submitted will always be in this format:

- supplierName - [PropRef]
- E.g. 'A J Cox - [SCOOPPP0000594]'

What I require from the string is the number (propRef) between the square brackets, I know I need to first find the charindex '-' and then replace the square brackets with nothing, but I am unsure exactly how to do that.

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the '[' and ']' chars are the delimiters, then just use them:

```
 DECLARE @SupplierName NVARCHAR(50) = 'A J Cox - [SCOOPPP0000594]'
 SELECT SUBSTRING(@SupplierName, 1 + CHARINDEX('[', @SupplierName), CHARINDEX(']', @SupplierName) - CHARINDEX('[', @SupplierName) - 1)
```

Comment: No need to use `CHARINDEX(']', @SupplierName)` `CHARINDEX` searches the string but you already know where it is (at the end).  Use LEN its a little more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Something like (assuming MSSQL)

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING('A J Cox - [SCOOPPP0000594]',
             CHARINDEX('[', 'A J Cox - [SCOOPPP0000594]') + 1,  
             LEN('A J Cox - [SCOOPPP0000594]') - (CHARINDEX('[', 'A J Cox - [SCOOPPP0000594]') + 1)
             )
```

Or

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(YourFieldName,
             CHARINDEX('[', YourFieldName) + 1,  
             LEN(YourFieldName) - (CHARINDEX('[', YourFieldName) + 1)
```

One less `CHARINDEX`, One less search on the string!

Answer (score 0):

XML can work nicely too:

```
DECLARE @SupplierName NVARCHAR(50) = 'A J Cox - [SCOOPPP0000594]'
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(replace( @SupplierName,'[','<sup>'),']','</sup>') AS XML).query('//sup/text()')
```